# Is constrainLayout stable enough to use in real project?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

in the Past years i found a different version of constraint layout alpha, beta and most of the time i see the people who share article about constraint layout said that it has bug inside. 
in the middle of my big project i found that my UI which uses relative and mostly linear layout is too slow because my client said that the UI should have to be same and has no scroll in all devices tablet, phone then i had to use weight and inner linear layout and that cause slow UI.
in my case constraint layout is like a hero and can solve much of my problem but i don't know it is stable enough to use in real project.
thanks

Comment: If you test it and it works for you, use it.

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns do u have experience in developing native android   !!!!

Comment: No but I have lots of development experience.  What works for YOU is what counts.  Try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

[Latest release](http://tools.android.com/recent/constraintlayout102isnowavailable) As you can see it`a already released, so Android developers believe it is stable enough to use in production. As for is there bugs, there are bugs in all software. If it does what is supposed to do in your case- just use it